# sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states, understanding the different *_time columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups

I am going nuts trying to understand the meaning of the different time columns in the `sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states` system table.

We have a three node Always On Availability Group, where two of the nodes are sync and one async.  **We want to use the async node for reporting and want to find an accurate way to calculate the delay between the primary and async replica.**

Below is a snapshot of a query:

```
select synchronization_state_desc, 
       is_primary_replica, 
       last_sent_time, 
       last_received_time, 
       last_hardened_time, 
       last_redone_time, 
       last_commit_time
from sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states DRS 
where database_id = db_id('DBname')
```

[image]

**Edited the post to narrow down the question**

If I need to find the actual delay it takes for the data to appear on async node, which columns do I use?

Answer (score 3):

For a starter, here's the [Microsoft Docs Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-hadr-database-replica-states-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

As an aside, I suggest you do some reading into the mechanics of an availability group, purely so you can understand my answer. ([Microsoft Docs Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017))

As for the answer to your question, as normally in the case with questions around an RDBMS, it depends.

In this case is depends on what you mean by "...for data to appear"

Let's have a look at the columns in your question:

- last_sent_time,
- last_received_time,
- last_hardened_time,
- last_redone_time,
- last_commit_time

It is also worth noting that the System DMV you are referring to is at the **database level**

---

### **last_sent_time**

This time indicates the last time that the PRIMARY sent a Log Block to the available secondaries. This is the start of the *data synchronisation* process.

### **last_received_time**

This indicates the last time that the secondary received a log block.

### **last_hardened_time**

This indicates the last time that the secondary cached the recieved log block data to disk.

### **last_redone_time**

This is the time that the last LSN was redone on the target database.

### **last_commit_time**

This is the time of the last commit record was redone and reported back to the primary.

---

### **Summary**

Of the above, there are various entry-points of the data into the secondary systems.

The data first enters the server into memory at **last_received_time**

The data first enters the server on disk at **last_hardened_time**

The data first enters the database data files at **last_redone_time**

The data first becomes committed and available for reading by queries (outside of strange NOLOCK situations) at **last_commit_time**

I suspect that the answer to your question is the latter of the 4 concepts. There is a *small* overhead to the time in this column however, due to the transmission time of the data between the SECONDARY and PRIMARY. This is likely to be unimportant in calculations for determining the speed of data throughput though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I went through the documents and what you explained makes sense, but it does not relate to the values that I am seeing.  In my case, if you look at the first row in the  screenshot, last_sent_time 2:35:18.190, received_time  2:35:18.190, hardned_time 2:35:17.657.  So the hardned time is before the sent and receive time.  That would mean that the hardned time is referring to an older log block and not one that is sent or received.  Is my understanding correct?  if that is correct, is (getdate - last redone time) the best approach to calculate lag?

Comment: @user158327 They do not all refer to the same LSN / log blocks. The time is literally just a time - the likelyhood is that for the log block sent at time 2:35:18:190, the data has not yet been cached to disk. As you say, it is referring to an older log block. At a guess thinking about it, without constantly selecting values from this DMV into a separate table, I'm not sure this table alone is enough to get your answer in it's true form.

Comment: @user158327 This may help you https://www.sqlshack.com/measuring-availability-group-synchronization-lag/